# Validation error every time on save comment form

Tags: 7, forms, panels, chaos-tool-suite

Every time I try to leave comment on a content of a certain type I get this error:

> Validation error, please try again. If this error persists, please contact the site administrator.

Refreshing and resubmitting the comment manually does not fix the problem, I always get this issue. The content type in question is displayed via a Panels Node Template, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

I traced the problem down to the the panels pane that displayed the comments list. If the comments list was disabled, comment submission worked fine; turned back on the validation error returned.

Looks like this is caused by a [(likely) bug in CTOOLS](http://drupal.org/node/957894). The patch in [comment #1](http://drupal.org/node/957894#comment-3649810) fixed the issue.